# Test Coverage files in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to retrieve the coverage test info from Xcode 6 and failed in the attempt.
I'm flush out on applicationDidEnterBackground with __gcov_flush()
I set to YES both "Generate Debug Symbols", "Generate test Coverage files" and "Instrument program flow" as the Apple Technical Q&A explains. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1514/_index.html)

I run the app with LLVM 6.0 compiler.

I look for any .gcda files in Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/App.build also as Apple Q&A says.

I can not found any coverage file either this directory or elsewhere in my mac.

Seems this is the correct way to do it until Xcode 5.1.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found coverage files in `Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<MyApp - a bunch of random characters>/Build/Intermediates/MyIndex.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64`. Did you look there?

I've also found that these only seem to exist for Objective-C files - Swift files are not instrumented and therefore no coverage files appear.